# Sending HTTP Request Tibco Businessworks 6.x

Tags: tibco, businessworks

Basically I've got a finished Web Service, from which I need to call a specific operation. I tried to get my head around it by myself, but it doesn't work, or I don't get how to test it.

I have already imported the .wsdl file and called the web service using the Web Service Tester Interface of Businessworks, but I fail to recreate the connection using the designer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a SOAP Request Reply activity:

[image: SOAP Request Reply activity]

Click the "Browse" button to select the WSDL that you have already imported. Then, you will be prompted for the operation. Select the one you want to use and click **OK**:

[image]

**Additional information:**

For testing purposes I use this public web service for currency conversion:

http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL

You should see something like this by providing the parameters described [here](http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx) in the input tab of the activity:

[image]

Comment: I imported the .wsdl file via a provided URL.

However, I do not need to "create" a web service, because I only want to contact it. The web service itself was created and configured long ago, I just need to reach it via Businessworks

Comment: This looks like BW 5.x, I am using 6.x
I couldn't find a SOAPRequestReply, I tried SendHTTPRequest, but it doesn't work and I don't get why. http://imgur.com/iyiKYgB

I appreciate your effor.

Answer (score 0):

In BW6 you want to use the "Invoke" activity.  I would suggest that you drag a sample project (a good one is [binding/soap/http/bookstore/tibco.bw.sample.binding.soap.http.BookStore.zip] from the "File Explorer" panel in Business Studio (the lower-left panel) up to the "Project Explorer" panel on the upper-left.  This will unzip the sample project and add it to your workspace so you will have a valid sample BW6 soap project to use as a guide.

Comment: I just tried using the Bookstore Project as a guide, however there are errors as well as warnings. Two of them are WSDL problems, but I think I will use it as a general guide instead of a step-by-step guide.

Comment: "cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'location' must appear on element 'wsdl:import'."

Curiously, when trying to resolve my own wsdl via Web Service Tester, I also get the message "XSD: The location ' ' has not been resolved. I'm thinking these two are connected.

However, I do know other users of Tibco BW have reported errors handling wsdl in general, and that an imminent update should probably fix many issues with wsdl

Comment: Judging from the error messages you are providing, it appears that your wsdl is importing other resources such as xsd's or wsdl's.  The [WSDL specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_document-n) indicates that, "WSDL allows associating a namespace **with a document location** using an import statement".  Thus an import statement should also specify a location so as to allow BW6 to resolve the import and access the definitions within the imported resource.  That appears to be missing or incorrect in your wsdl.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I know that we import multiple other XSD files, but I made sure to alter their location so they match. I will check them again tomorrow to make sure